# Using FPSaveController how can we upload local files

Tags: ios, objective-c, filepicker, filepicker.io

I tried filepicker.io in IOS project. it's not provided dataURL in FPSaveController's object. Also don't know how can I use `- (void) saveFileName:(NSString *)filename To:(NSString *)path` method to save file on Amazon Server. If I use `FPPickerController` class to fetch media from web (not from local album) then it gives its url i.e. https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/...

I need help to upload media files over filepicker.io captured with `UIImagePickerController`.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you're looking to do? You want to take a local file (picked with UIImagePickerController) and upload it to S3?

Comment: Yes, If I use FPPickerController to get image from provided web sources i.e. dropbox, box, skydrive, etc. then it gives its file URL https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/...

Comment: If I use FPPickerController to get image from Camera or Camera Roll then how can I upload to S3 and get file URL. Also if I use UIImagePickerController to get image then how can I upload it to S3 and get file URL.